# NoResourceEntry-x REPL tree output

Tags: xamarin, tree, read-eval-print-loop

For some reason for the Xamarin Test app for which I am 100% sure that its elements have Ids, I can only see "NoResourceEntry".

Not sure what is the reason, but either it is related to Emulator, Target Framework or something else.

Did someone have this issue? And do you know what is causing it? 
I am running the simple test and just trying to trigger the REPL tree command
Please refer to screenshots below:

[REPL tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl7b5.jpg)
[Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31J0R.jpg)[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Vxy.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add AutomationId to each property.

e.g.    `<Button x:Name="Button1" AutomationId="Button1"`

This sets the label property, which you should now see in REPL using the tree commnand.

You can then do :

```
app.Tap(c => c.Marked("Button1"));
```

See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97202/why-do-views-in-my-app-not-have-ids for more details.

Comment: Yes but that is dev side, right? I don't have access to the code of the app, just have an apk.

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't realise you didn't have access to the code. The Developer will need to add AutomationId to all of the properties which will then be accessible via the APK.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the original answer is valid, you can get the elements using the Text property.

e.g.  `<Button x:Name="Button1" Text="My Button"`

and then to retrieve the element: `var result = app.Query(m => m.Marked("My Button"));`

In your circumstance this a possible approach.